# I am looking for UITextFieldDelegate sample code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am looking for `UITextFieldDelegate` sample code. Please teach when knowing.

Comment: I don't want to teach someone who can't even write a valid sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Here's Apple's docs: [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

In the first section, they have a bunch of links to sample code.  See:

**Related sample code**

- [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913)
- [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243)
- [SimpleURLConnections](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009245)
- [TaggedLocations](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TaggedLocations/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008914)
- [UICatalog](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710)

Unless you ask for anything more specific, this is the best I can do.