# how to know if textfield value changd while data entered from a button ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uitextfielddelegate, nsnotification

how can i know if a textfield value is changed while i'm entering data from  some buttons rather than from keyboard .I have tried  UITextfield delegate methods but it works only  if i am tusing the keyboard.I am using different UIButtons to enter data on the  textfield,so  UITextfield delegates wont work here.Please share your thoughts on the approache's i should use here.Should i use NSNotification??but  how to know textfield value changed on data entered from UIButton.

The references i have used are
[Listen to a value change of my text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164471/listen-to-a-value-change-of-my-text-field)

[How to check text field input at real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483967/how-to-check-text-field-input-at-real-time)

Comment: May be this tutorial can help you. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-custom-keyboard-views-for-customized-text-field-input/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add key-value observing on that particular UITextField

**for Example**

```
[myTextField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:0 context:nil];

// then implement this method

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context 
{
        if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"text"] && [object isEqual:myTextField]) 
        {
            // here your logic on text change
        }
}
```